# Easiest/best way to only allow certain IP ranges for access

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I'm looking for the easiest/best way to only certain IP ranges to access my Ubuntu 20.04 installation. I would mainly like this so I can block web traffic (apache), but a full server block would be best.

I realize that a hardware option is best for this, but I can't afford that. I also realize that 'easiest' and 'best' don't always go together.

Also, does having more IP ranges slow down the server?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter all IP traffic except the one you want quite easily on most Linux installations. Remember that when doing this you might lose access to server.

Here is a small base that might work.

```sh
# Allow some related traffic
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Allow single source ip
iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/net -j ACCEPT
# Drop everything else
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Before running the last drop line which activates everything, you can use `iptables -vnL` which shows you counters for when rule matches, make sure that it does.

Doing ip-filtering does use CPU cycles, but so does answering any packets. This is almost never a concern unless you are doing complex rules on high throughput. this is not complex rules.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this!